# Find an array in a 2d array with float values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of arrays, and I want to search through it to find an array (not a value).

```
values = np.array([[0.73123909, 0.73298429, 0.73472949, 0.73647469, 1.        ],
                   [0.72949389, 0.46596859, 0.39441536, 0.87260035, 1.        ],
                   [0.2600349 , 0.05235602, 0.73298429, 0.96684119, 1.        ],
                   [0.83071553, 0.37172775, 0.7452007 , 0.08202443, 1.        ],
                   [0.27923211, 0.28097731, 0.28272251, 0.28446771, 1.        ]])

item = np.array([0.73123909, 0.73298429, 0.73472949, 0.73647469, 1.        ])
index = np.where(values == item)
```

I expect to get a result similar to `index = 0` or `(array([0]),)`
But I get

```
(array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,]),
array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ]))
```

Similar answers target integers and won't work for float numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
>>> np.where(np.isclose(values, item).all(1))
(array([0], dtype=int64),)
```

By the way, don't check equality with `==` if you're dealing with floats, but instead use `isclose`.